# How do I fix the layout size with a background picture properly in Android?

Tags: android, layout, background, keyboard, scrollview

I need help with my layout.xml file size. I am probably missing something basic. I have created a search-function with a EditText, SearchButton and a ListView where I will display the search results.

Everytime you click on the EditText I need to make sure the background picture does'nt get resized when the softkeyboard is displayed, therefor my whole layout is placed in a ScrollView. That's basicly the only reason why I am using a ScrollView. But the ScrollView creates another problem aswell, look at the picture below:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=6p3yix&s=6

For some reason my background picture refuses to fill the whole "background" area. Look at the bottom of the picture where it is black. So when I am testing on a phone with large screens it gets black at the bottom. How can I manage to fill the whole "background" area with my background-picture? Please help!

**Edit**: I have tested to use the layout.xml file without a ScrollView but have not made it work since without it, the the keyboard will change the size of the background picture. I have also tryed to use adjustPan in the android manifest file without any luck. Only solution that worked is with ScrollView, but now instead I get this problem with the background-pictures size...  / Thanx!

**My xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/sorted_teams_scroll"
android:isScrollContainer="false">

<TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_search_task"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:weightSum="1.0" 
        android:background="@drawable/orginalbild01"
        >

        <TableRow>

              <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                 android:layout_weight="0.05">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_task_field"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.65"
                android:hint="@string/SearchTaskHint" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_task_button"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:text="@string/Search" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.05" >
            </TextView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:paddingLeft="40dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_task_column_names"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_task_column_names1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_task_column_names2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.33"
                android:textStyle="bold" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/search_task_progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminateOnly="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:paddingRight="18dp"
             >

            <ListView

                android:id="@+id/search_task_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="355dp"
                android:gravity="left" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have problem only with keyboard then...

just try this to disable the layout resize when keyboard is popped up -
In your manifest file add this to your activity...

> `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

Pls post complete code... in above code you set background for table layout.. how it will apply for full background.. post your code without scrollview...